# Zend 1 with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, zend-framework

I would like to know which this best practice of using and the recommended way to use angularJs with a zend1 or zend 2 back-end application.

Is there any recommended project structure?

Should I integrate angular.min.js in layout.phtml file and use directive there?

Comment: Questions of opinion don't really fit on SO and I believe this is one of those cases.  Personally would argue that the backend should not be aware of what front end is consuming it and shouldn't be directly tied to any particular front end.  This way you can have multiple clients that consume the same service without rewriting or patching the service for each client.  So if you ask me split them completely, the API should use JSON for the request/response body and otherwise Angular or any other client is none the wiser to the underlying implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I asked for files organisation and project structure.

Comment: Perhaps I missed the main focus of the question, if you are asking about angular project file structure would suggest checking out John Papa's angular style guide or Todd Motto's or just search for Angular Style Guide.  Most of these include some prescribed folder/file structure for the static assets.  With regard to the backend I'll stick with what I said before :)

Comment: The general gist would be you have an index.html file where you load scripts (or use a plugin system to do this for you either through build tools or runtime tools like SystemJS particularly if you're using angular 2).  You would split the files up so all the related files for some bit of functionality are defined on some module and your main app module would depend on all the sub-modules (depending on project complexity that amount of breaking up modules may be overkill)  In the end can use gulp/grunt/some build system to compile all the JS into one minified file.

Comment: I think that zend as a back-end framework sould provide  REST api for the client side with angular. And those web service should be consumed as angular resssource (ngRessource) my care is about templating systeme, because zend impose a layout system for templating how can can I combine this concept with angular (directiive+ tow way data binding ...

Comment: you could use both personally use laravel on the back end somewhat often and they also have a templating system but for the most part I've safely ignored it... with being the one exception where I had to work around a few things that expected a server side template, imagine you could do the same with Zend.  You can possibly have both doing template work but can get more confusing where problems lie when they arise... sorry typing on tablet with some bad completion

Comment: Retracted my vote to close now that I better understand what you're asking for here.  Still feel it is somewhat opinion based but perhaps could be somewhat directly answered by someone with more Zend + angular experience.

Comment: I will start with a zend MVC Skeleton Application and bootstrap the view with an angular logique using scoop directive. The idea is to use services provides  by zend inject data in html view. Stil waitnig for the best recommandations and practices to combine those 2 technologies :)